# How to keep special double quote in a string in VB.NET? (unicode U+0093 and U+0094)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, utf-8, visual-studio-2013

I want to have the following line of code (shortened for clarity) :

```
Dim AllowedChar as string = "0..9 A..Za..z!$'()+,-.;=@[]^_`€‚ƒ„…†‡ˆ‰Š‹ŒŽ‘’“”•..."
```

But whenever I save my file, Visual Studio (2010 and 2013) replaces `“”` with `""`.

How can I stop this behavior?

Comment: try this : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/613dxh46%28v=VS.71%29.aspx

Comment: I find it ugly, but it works. Please post this as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: I don't think it would be that ugly. You have `Dim AllowedChar as string = "stuff...." + chrW(0093) + chrW(0094) + "moreStuff"`

Comment: It's exactly what I find ugly :p

Comment: Not sure if this would bring you back to the same issue... but you can set variables with `chrW(0093)` or even put it into an array. Might make it a bit neater if its a big concern

Answer (score 0):

2 options:

1. Escape the double curly quote by typing it twice. ie: ““  and ””. (Curly Quotes are escaped the same way straight ones are.
2. Use the ascii code and concatenate the string:  AllowedChar = AllowedChar + "“" + "”".  (8220 and 8221 are the ascii codes for curly quotes).

Here's a similar answer from another question that should help:
[Using left double quotation marks in strings in VB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4665510/using-left-double-quotation-marks-in-strings-in-vb)